# Getting 202 instead of 200 using Rest assured or Robot Framework

Tags: api, automated-tests, robotframework, rest-assured, endpoint

I have performed a GET request as follows:

**TEST1** : Using Rest assured:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = my_BaseUri;

Response response = given().header("x-ibm-client-id", my_XibmClientId).auth().preemptive()
    .oauth2(my_accessToken)
    .accept(ContentType.JSON).when()
    .get(my_BasePath + "/" + my_processId)
    .then().log().all()
    .extract().response();
```

**TEST2** : Using Robot Framework:

```
${headers}=   Create Dictionary    x-ibm-client-id=${my_xIbmClientId}    Authorization=Bearer ${my_AccessToken}    Accept=application/json

${response}=    Get Request    mysession    ${my_BasePath}/${my_processId}    headers=${headers}
```

So the issue is: I always get a status **202** (accepted) instead of **200**. However, it works properly with the POSTMAN (the response status is 200).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you compare rest-assured log and postman log? Any differences?

Comment: Hi  @lucas-nguyen,   
What I noticed is that the log contains `content-type: application/json` in the response headers of POSTMAN (the status is 200). On the other hand, with rest-assured I can't see it in the log (the status is 202)
Please, do you have a solution for that

Comment: Double check with request log, not response log. You need to find out what is the difference between request of 2 tools (RA and postman).

Comment: Should i check what exactly in the log ? Because, the printed log shows only the status and the response headers. So, as montioned in the top : the difference is the status (I have 200 with Postman and 202 with rest-assured. For your information, i passes the same informations in the Get request with both tools. Thank u some much for you help

Comment: I got me wrong. What I want to point out is the `request log`, NOT response log. You should add code to log `request` in RA.

Comment: No problem it's correct. So, can you show me how To do that please (I will search a solution in my side in the same time). Thank you

Comment: You mean that i should use log().all() with rest-assured before send request to server .... right ? And with POSTMAN where can i check the request log ?

Comment: I did the check and i have the same infos as follows: 
`x-ibm-client-id: my_x-ibm-client-id`

`Authorization: Bearer my_accessToken`

`Accept: */*`

`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

`Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: In RA and robot fw, you set `Accpect: application/json` but in postman, it was `Accept: */*`. This is the only thing, I thin, may matter.

Comment: I even tried with 'Accpect: application/json' but unfortunately it also does not always work (the same issue ! ). Thank you si much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
${headers}=   Create Dictionary    x-ibm-client-id=${my_xIbmClientId}    
Authorization=Bearer ${my_AccessToken}    Content-Type=text/plain

${response}=    Get Request    mysession    ${my_BasePath}/${my_processId}    
headers=${headers}   alias=API
```

I just added content-type= text/plain

Comment: Does not work Also.  Thank you so much Ahmed

Comment: Can you share the logs.

Comment: I tried another solution. but, i have the same status 202 instead of 200   

`Response response2 = given().auth().preemptive().oauth2(accessToken)
     .header("x-ibm-client-id", my_client_id).contentType("application/json")
     .pathParam("processId", my_processId).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).when().log().all()
     .get(my_BasePathStart() + "/{processsId}").then().log().all().extract().response();`
  

However, when i tested with POSTMAN => it works properly (getting status 200): 
 

`GET   https:BaseURI/BasePath/my_processId`
i use OAuth2 to generate accessToken

Comment: hi Ahmed, here is my logs of the request:– 

`Request method: GET`
`Request URI: BaseURL/BasePath/my_processId`
`Path params: processsId=my_processId`
`Headers:  Authorization=Bearer accessToken`
`x-ibm-client-id=my_clientId`
`Accept=application/json`
`Content-Type=application/json`